# Which is faster? Using a mutex or spawning a new thread?

Tags: parallel-processing

I have a loop operating on IO, and half of the work needs to be done in a 2nd thread. (I'm using pthreads.)

Is it faster to spawn a new thread (and then join it) with each iteration of my loop? Or is it faster to spawn a 2nd thread a single time and put the 2nd thread in a loop as well and use a semaphore to control it? (I.e. first thread posts to the semaphore, and the 2nd thread waits on the semaphore.)

I'm working with C code on an Android tablet.

Comment: My guess would be that a mutex is at least an order of magnitude faster, but measure it.

Comment: ... and share the result